# How to change default localhost port for React App

Tags: reactjs, localhost

I downloaded the React App package from the link [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).
The default port it assigns is **port:3000**

How to Change this port to a custom port like *3002 or 3006* ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

modify part of package.json from:

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

for Linux and MacOS to:

```
"start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start"
```

Windows to:

```
"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"
```

Comment: If you want a cross-platform solution, check out [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

Comment: how do you explicitly add the local ip to open in firewall?

Comment: put `PORT=5000` in the file called `.env` also works.

Comment: @Valorad thanks your solution prevented me from adding the port to the script